# select2 fails in Firefox without a decent error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I have a functional implementation of [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html) jquery plugin here:
http://ffx.gelatinpixel.com/files/subs/v0.4_so.html - working fine in Chrome and IE9 (Win7 VM), but fails in Firefox.

I am extracting a list from a json file and generate the entries to be added as options in the select element, but they do not show up. Strangely though, their value (clicking on a blank, yet highlighted option) still executes the search / select query and populates the table below.

I am on Firefox 26.0 right now.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, been hooked on this for over half a day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your populateDropDown function: subOpt.innerText = suburbs[i];

Try this one:

```
subOpt.text = suburbs[i];
```

Because Firefox does not support innerText.
[Firefox support textContent not innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

I think instead of using native document createElement function, it is better to use jQuery.

Because jQuery covers these differences between browsers.

Comment: Thanks, I will take that advice on board. MIght as well make use of it if jquery already loaded - thanks! 

PS: updated the above link for future reference

Comment: Same to you:)
RE link updated I meant I updated the sample page from .innerText to .text